# desire2learn: create user API path

Tags: desire2learn

I am trying to use the path

```
POST /d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/users/
```

and am running into an error. I'm hoping there is something not in the documentation that I am missing, because from what I can tell, this should work.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2013 18:37:07 GMT
```

The data I'm sending looks like this:

```
{
    "OrgDefinedId":"190006002",
    "FirstName":"Jesty",
    "MiddleName":"Q",
    "LastName":"McTest",
    "ExternalEmail":"privateemail@gmail.com",
    "UserName":"190006002",
    "RoleId":115,
    "IsActive":true,
    "SendCreationEmail":true
}
```

My PHP code looks like this at the moment:

```
    $random_hash = "xxBOUNDARYxx";
    $request ="--".$random_hash.
              "\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n$data\r\n\r\n--".
              $random_hash;

    $length=strlen($request);
    $url = $opContext->createAuthenticatedUri($url,"POST");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HTTP/1.1", "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xxBOUNDARYxx","Content-Length:".$length));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    return curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after several hours of tinkering I figured it out. The original code I posted was based off of code that worked for posting the profile image through the API. The code for just posting JSON was much simpler. Here is a generic PHP function for sending JSON to Valence through the POST method

```
/*
*  $opContext is your user context object
*  $url is the route
*  $data is the well formed JSON in a string ( use json_encode() ) 
*  $ct is the count of json fields
*/

static function basic_post($opContext,$url,$data,$ct){
    $url = $opContext->createAuthenticatedUri($url,"POST"); 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,$ct);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    return curl_exec($ch);  
}
```

Comment: That is correct. When all you need to send is a standard JSON structure, and nothing else, you simply set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` and send the JSON in the body. If you need to post file data, then, generally, you need a `multipart-mixed` content type, with the first part being a JSON descriptor for the file, and the second part being the file data.

Comment: What's nice is that I now have generic functions for get, put, post and delete for valence. So I have a nice layer of abstraction that lets me focus on the task at hand rather than correctly setting up curl.

Comment: I agree entirely; this is one of the reasons I added the `data` and `service` helper modules to the Python client SDK. I can't claim that they're awesomely well written as I'm a Python newb, but that helped me solve this same class of problem.